# Using java-google-translate-text-to-speech on android

Tags: java, android, translation, google-translate

I need to translate inputed text from one language to another, trying to use [this](https://code.google.com/p/java-google-translate-text-to-speech/) but have problem. This code:

```
Thread one = new Thread() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    Translator translate = Translator.getInstance();
                    String text = translate.translate("I am programmer", Language.ENGLISH, Language.PORTUGUESE);
                    Log.d("TEXT: ",text);
                } catch(Exception v) {
                    Log.d("ERR: ", v.toString());
                }
            }
        };
one.start();
```

Throws error:

```
W/System.err: java.io.FileNotFoundException: http://translate.google.com.br/translate_a/t?client=t&text=I%20am%20programmer&hl=en&sl=en&tl=pt&multires=1&prev=btn&ssel=0&tsel=0&sc=1
W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:206)
W/System.err:     at com.gtranslate.utils.WebUtils.source(WebUtils.java:24)
W/System.err:     at com.gtranslate.parsing.ParseTextTranslate.parse(ParseTextTranslate.java:19)
W/System.err:     at com.gtranslate.Translator.translate(Translator.java:37)
W/System.err:     at org.reikartz.mashkov.recyclerview.MainActivity$1$1.run(MainActivity.java:74)
```

I don't know, what am i doing wrong.

Comment: can you print some more info? v.printStackTrace(); and edit your post?

Comment: FileNotFoundException in HttpURLConnection is generally occurred because of bad request or library errors once update all your build.gradel file dependence related and check your manifest permissions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally i find out, that http links not valid (in some unknown cause) and desided to use yandex api https://github.com/rmtheis/yandex-translator-java-api

Comment: how to use this Project . please answer me as soon as possible.

Comment: You need to import it in your project and then use example from it's github page

Comment: I can't import it in my project as module . how to do ?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that the **language** should be **installed** in your device as well if you need to convert it. The **file** of **Portuguese** is not present in your device it is throwing `FileNotFoundException`.

Answer (score 0):

I think the actual problem is that java-google-translate-text-to-speech is ancient and does not generate valid HTTP requests (the URL from the stack trace gives a 503, which is why you get the FileNotFoundException from the HttpURLConnnection).

You probably want to use the [Translate API v2 Client for Java](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/apis/translate/v2).