# How do I import Java library into Android Studio?

Tags: java, android

I have googled for hours and tried many methods, but nothing worked. It should be simple to add a simple Java library into Android Studio. I want to have this to work with my Android Studio project:

https://github.com/rmtheis/yandex-translator-java-api

Can someone please provide step-by-step help? I know Android Studio supports this since it apparently works for a guy here. Unfortunately, he wasn't telling how he did to import:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/34448943/9276801

So thankful for help!

Comment: You need to add a dependency in build.gradle.

Comment: What library you trying to add? You trying with simple *.jar / *.aar or your library is somewhere on maven repos?

Comment: @AndreiVinogradov Not sure if I can understand your question. I want to have the whole thing from that repo on provided link.

Comment: @GabeSechan Yeah. Maybe you're right. Watched those codes and it doesn't seem very hard to write.

Answer (score 0):

Clone the repo somewhere on your computer. Then please follow this link: https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/android-library with explanation

Comment: It says I need to build the library. How do I do it? Tried to build it with gradle, but there are no dependencies.

Comment: Open the code in the android studio and then perform build. After build finish successfully check app/build/output and there you will find .aar file you can include to another project