# How to import java library for android studio

Tags: java, android, api, jar

I am trying to use [Send Pulse](https://github.com/sendpulse/sendpulse-rest-api-java) which is web `smtp` server to send mails to my customers from an android app. I discovered their java rest api library but I could not import their library as I could not find an external `jar` file on the site.

How do I implement this library on my android studio project?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53341343/how-do-i-import-java-library-into-android-studio

Comment: remember, you have to use search before asking

Comment: Just download the code in a module or in your app. Where is the problem?

Comment: do I need to use retrofit or volley with this api? just asking.

Comment: @bensofter, do you understand what either retrofit or volley do?